# Should I remove these packages installed with `build-dep`?

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, 22.04, dependencies

In order to install a Kwin decoration ([Zren /
material-decoration](https://github.com/Zren/material-decoration)) the command `build-dep` was required, which I understand means installing packages needed to compile another package. A lot of those were installed and after installing that decoration (that I don't even like) now I was thinking to remove those packages.

`sudo apt build-dep breeze` triggered the installation of the following packages:

```
breeze-dev dh-python gir1.2-gudev-1.0 kinit-dev kscreenlocker-dev libblkid-dev libbrotli-dev libcap-dev libclang1-14 libdrm-dev   libegl1-mesa-dev libepoxy-dev libevdev-dev libfontconfig-dev libfreetype-dev libfreetype6-dev libgbm-dev libgles-dev libgles1  libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libgudev-1.0-dev libice-dev libinput-dev libkf5activities-dev  libkf5archive-dev libkf5bookmarks-dev libkf5completion-dev libkf5crash-dev libkf5declarative-dev libkf5doctools-dev libkf5idletime-dev  libkf5jobwidgets-dev libkf5kio-dev libkf5newstuff-dev libkf5newstuffwidgets5 libkf5notifications-dev libkf5plasma-dev libkf5runner-dev  libkf5solid-dev libkf5sonnet-dev libkf5sonnet-dev-bin libkf5textwidgets-dev libkwaylandserver-dev liblcms2-dev libllvm14 libmount-dev  libmtdev-dev libopengl-dev libpciaccess-dev libpcre16-3 libpcre2-32-0 libpcre2-dev libpcre2-posix3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5  libpipewire-0.3-dev libpng-dev libqaccessibilityclient-qt5-dev libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5sensors5-dev libselinux1-dev libsepol-dev  libsm-dev libspa-0.2-dev libudev-dev libwacom-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-composite0-dev libxcb-cursor-dev libxcb-damage0-dev  libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-icccm4-dev libxcb-image0-dev libxcb-keysyms1-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render-util0-dev libxcb-render0-dev  libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-util-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb-xtest0 libxcb-xtest0-dev libxcursor-dev  libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxrender-dev plasma-wayland-protocols qdoc-qt5 qhelpgenerator-qt5 qt5-assistant  qtattributionsscanner-qt5 qtbase5-private-dev qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools qtwayland5-dev-tools uuid-dev wayland-protocols
```

and `sudo apt build-dep kwin`  involved installing these:

```
autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev debhelper debugedit dh-autoreconf dh-strip-nondeterminism diffstat dwz extra-cmake-modules  gettext intltool-debian libaliased-perl libapt-pkg-perl libarchive-zip-perl libb-hooks-endofscope-perl libb-hooks-op-check-perl  libcapture-tiny-perl libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-method-modifiers-perl libclass-xsaccessor-perl libconfig-tiny-perl  libconst-fast-perl libcpanel-json-xs-perl libdata-dpath-perl libdata-messagepack-perl libdata-optlist-perl libdata-validate-domain-perl  libdata-validate-ip-perl libdata-validate-uri-perl libdebhelper-perl libdevel-callchecker-perl libdevel-size-perl  libdevel-stacktrace-perl libdynaloader-functions-perl libegl-dev libemail-address-xs-perl libexception-class-perl libexporter-tiny-perl  libffi-dev libfile-find-rule-perl libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libfont-ttf-perl libgl-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libglx-dev  libhtml-html5-entities-perl libimport-into-perl libio-interactive-perl libio-prompt-tiny-perl libio-string-perl libipc-run3-perl  libiterator-perl libiterator-util-perl libjson-maybexs-perl libkdecorations2-dev libkf5attica-dev libkf5auth-dev libkf5auth-dev-bin  libkf5codecs-dev libkf5config-dev libkf5config-dev-bin libkf5configwidgets-dev libkf5coreaddons-dev libkf5coreaddons-dev-bin  libkf5dbusaddons-dev libkf5globalaccel-dev libkf5guiaddons-dev libkf5i18n-dev libkf5iconthemes-dev libkf5itemviews-dev libkf5kcmutils-dev  libkf5package-dev libkf5service-dev libkf5style-dev libkf5wayland-dev libkf5widgetsaddons-dev libkf5windowsystem-dev libkf5xmlgui-dev  liblist-compare-perl liblist-moreutils-perl liblist-moreutils-xs-perl liblist-someutils-perl liblist-utilsby-perl  libmodule-implementation-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libmoo-perl libmoox-aliases-perl libmouse-perl libnamespace-clean-perl  libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ipv6addr-perl libnet-netmask-perl libnetaddr-ip-perl libnumber-compare-perl libpackage-stash-perl  libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl libpath-tiny-perl libperlio-gzip-perl libperlio-utf8-strict-perl libproc-processtable-perl  libpthread-stubs0-dev libqt5quicktest5 libqt5scripttools5 libqt5x11extras5-dev librole-tiny-perl libsereal-decoder-perl  libsereal-encoder-perl libsigsegv2 libsort-versions-perl libstrictures-perl libsub-exporter-perl libsub-exporter-progressive-perl  libsub-identify-perl libsub-install-perl libsub-name-perl libsub-override-perl libsub-quote-perl libsyntax-keyword-try-perl  libterm-readkey-perl libtext-glob-perl libtext-levenshteinxs-perl libtext-markdown-discount-perl libtext-xslate-perl  libtime-duration-perl libtime-moment-perl libtool libunicode-utf8-perl libvariable-magic-perl libvulkan-dev libwayland-bin libwayland-dev  libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxml-libxml-perl libxml-namespacesupport-perl libxml-sax-base-perl  libxml-sax-perl libxs-parse-keyword-perl libyaml-libyaml-perl lintian lzip lzop m4 patchutils pkg-config pkg-kde-tools po-debconf
```

It seems they are not easy to uninstall anyway, because when I try to remove the first group of installed dependencies (installed with `sudo apt build-dep breeze`) I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package  gettext
E: Unable to locate package  libcapture-tiny-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libconst-fast-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libdata-validate-ip-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libdevel-stacktrace-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libffi-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libhtml-html5-entities-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libiterator-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libkf5codecs-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libkf5dbusaddons-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libkf5package-dev
E: Unable to locate package  liblist-compare-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libmodule-implementation-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libnet-domain-tld-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libparams-classify-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libpthread-stubs0-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libsereal-encoder-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libsub-identify-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libterm-readkey-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libtime-duration-perl
E: Unable to locate package  libx11-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libxml-sax-perl
```

When I try to remove the second group (the one installed with `sudo apt build-dep kwin`) I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package  libegl1-mesa-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libglib2.0-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libkf5archive-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libkf5jobwidgets-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libkf5solid-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libmtdev-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libpipewire-0.3-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libsm-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libxcb-glx0-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libxcb-shape0-dev
E: Unable to locate package  libxfixes-dev
E: Unable to locate package  qtattributionsscanner-qt5
```

I imagine that if I exclude those I can uninstall the rest.

***but should I uninstall them?***

And is there a different procedure of uninstalling packages installed with `build-dep`?

Comment: Is that the whole command or was there more to it? What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @David - I have updated the question with all commands involved. This is Kubuntu 22.04 LTS.